# Conditional formatting based on selection from a dropdown list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet that is used as a sort of a schedule. Each person has their own ID number and the ID number is shown in a distinct cell. So if my ID is 41, I might see myself scheduled 9-12 on one day, etc.  The problem is that finding your number over multiple pages and permutations is messy. So I have a dropdown where you can select your number, and I want to have this highlight any occurrences of your ID number on the schedule.

I tried using conditional formatting>use a formula to determine which cells to format> `=ISNUMBER(FIND(AT8, C10))` where AT8 is my drop down and C10 is the start of the schedule table.

This works BUT if the person's ID number is "2" then any cell with a 2 is highlighted (12, 22, etc.).  How can I get this to match only the exact value and highlight only cells that exactly match?

Comment: This would be easier to answer with some sample data but wouldn't `=$AT$8` work? Side note: you can limit the cells affected by the conditional format to only those cells that include ID numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select cell c10 and define the CF formula rule

```
=C10=$AT$8
```

Now use the format painter to copy the CF format down column C and/or cross other columns  you also want highlighted.

FYI if you have Office 365, the FILTER function could come in handy. On a new sheet, say B1 is your lookup ID, then you can display only B1's schedule with e.g.

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A10:AT1000, Sheet1!C10:C1000=B1, "")
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I couldn't get that to work. It ended up highlighting the entire row, and not just the cell. Here's the file I am using: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qn3llvvxgeOa8_m68fRu5pji56xO4FW7/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113062779684939758397&rtpof=true&sd=true. 

Its excel, I am just sharing from my google drive.

 Thank you for the help!

Comment: Ah see I assumed you wanted to highlight the whole row. Edited my answer. Just removed the dollar sign from `$C10` that locked the comparison to column C

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked!